# No Show of bigger picture (prev() click()attr())

Tags: jquery, html

I use the following code to show the bigger pic.

```
<body>
<div id="Rand">
<a href="#" alt="img/groot/img1.jpg" id="unique name of picture" class="BiggerPic">
<img src="img/thumb/img1.jpg" />
</a>
<a href="#" alt="img/groot/img2.jpg" id="unique name of picture" class="BiggerPic">
<img src="img/thumb/img2.jpg" />
</a>
<a href="#" alt="img/groot/img2.jpg" id="unique name of picture" class="BiggerPic">
<img src="img/thumb/img2.jpg" />
</a>
</div>
<div id="ShowBiggerDivIMG" style="display: none;">
<img id=ShowBiggerIMG src="" />
</div>
</body>

$(document).ready(function(){
var imgScr = $('.BiggerPic').prev('a').attr('alt');
$('.ImageMagnifier').click(function(){
$('#ShowBiggerDivIMG').fadeIn(600);
$('#ShowBiggerIMG').attr('src', imgScr);
})
});
```

The only thing he return is the last link of the last picture.
How do i get the alt (link) of the activ clicked Thumbnail to replace with the src of img(#ShowBiggerIMG)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to get the alt of the clicked image

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       var imgScr;
    $('.BiggerPic').click(function(){
       imgScr =$(this).attr('alt');           
     });

        $('.ImageMagnifier').click(function(){
           $('#ShowBiggerDivIMG').fadeIn(600);
           $('#ShowBiggerIMG').attr('src', imgScr);
        });
    });
```

Comment: It was the most helpfull one!

At first it retunt the good one, the next click returned the first one en than give a flash to right one.

So i only needed to clear the src from ShowBiggerIMG and it it is fixed!